# Border and dimensions not working in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

I have been searching to a resolution to this for hours, but I still cannot find one! My new personal site works perfectly in webkit browsers, but the formatting mucks up in firefox. Firstly, the pictures have borders, and secondly, there are only two per row when there are meant to be three. The CSS I am using for the content is below:

```
.imagewrapper {
    display: inline-table;
    margin: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.imagedisplay {
    height: 122px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
.imagedisplay:hover {
    height: 122px;
    opacity:0.4;
    border-o
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: I've yet to find the key with the width differences in webkit vs. FF (FF renders things wider), but I always use a separate stylesheet if I can't get everyone to agree and use the "@-moz-document url-prefix(){}" selector to target FF.  Using a reset stylesheet helps in some cases as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line before the `-moz-border-radius` is invalid and not closed. It continues to the next line, since there's no semicolon, and eats anything before the next semicolon.

```
border-o                     /* <--- Here lies the problem. Remove it. */
-moz-border-radius: 7px;
```

Comment: I see three images per row at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XMsnr/show/. @jack Also, use `<!DOCTYPE html>` instead of `<!DOCTYPE .. HTML 4 ...>`.

Comment: Thanks, every things working now, apart from the border-radius on the images isn't showing up???!!!!

Comment: @jacktheripper Works fine here. Did you add `-moz-border-radius:7px;` to your CSS? Did you not accidentally leave a character in the CSS, causing the rule to be ignored again?

Comment: No I'm using .imagedisplay {
 border: 0;
 height: 122px;
 -moz-border-radius: 7px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
 border-radius: 7px;
}

Comment: @jacktheripper In Firefox 10.0.1, it works as intended. In Firefox 3.0.3, the borders are also rounded. So, I wonder: In which Firefox browser do you observe this problem? It's very likely that you've made a typo, to get it not to work.

Comment: I'm using 3.6.3 on a mac, and I'm viewing the site as it is now uploaded to the FTP server online

Comment: 3.6.3 is ancient.  Even for a 3.6 release: it's literally 20+ security updates out of date (current 3.6 update is 3.6.26).  I really suggest actually testing in a current Firefox release, because no actual user that uses Firefox would be using 3.6.3.